# Difference between control source and row source in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I know there are threads with the answer for this question but as a beginner I am having a really hard time understanding the difference between these two. I am learning Access and have not learnt about SQL statements yet. Most explanation to this question consists of SQL code that I do not understand. If you could explain the difference for a beginner that would be great.

Comment: These are unrelated subjects. Asking for the difference between these is like asking for the difference between a car and a bicycle, you will have to explain what both are, and to learn what both are, you should just read the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a combobox in your form, it will both have a row source and a control source. The control source is the field in the underlying table where the actual values are stored. The row source is the source of the list of values to select from.
Example: You got a table with flowers. One field is color. You want to limit which colors to enter for the flowers. The you make a table called flower_colors.
In your flower form, you then have a combobox. Its control source will be colors from the table flower and the row source will be flower_colors.